# Sort elements by a value calculated on the go (not stored)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, elasticsearch, eloquent

In my project I'm using `Laravel 5.5` with `Eloquent` and `Scout` drivers to build a sort of search engine API endpoint.

In my scenario I have a SQL table `items` that has a `price_factor` property.
The table is also stored inside an `Elasticsearch` index.

With this value and with the number of the user related with that item, I can calculate the right price of the object.

An easy example is the item with `id: 1` has `price_factor: 2` and it is related to `5 users`.
The right price of the item is `2 * 5 = 10`, of course.

Now, I have to query all results and use `where conditions`, sorting them by that calcolated property, and return paginated results.

For example: get all items with price between 5 and 10, sort them by `price` and paginate by 10 elements per page.

In `Eloquent` I will write:

```
// Set filters to be applied
$filters = [
    ['price', '>', 5],
    ['price', '<', 10],
];
// Sort by "update_at", or "price"
$sort = "price";
// Order by "ASC" mode
$order = "ASC";
// Number of rows per page
$rows = 10;

// Get items
$result = Item::orderBy(
    $sort,
    $order
// Get related user with item record, where has...
)->with(['users'])->whereHas(
    // Take users related models
    'users',
    // Take the model related ("user") and use filters
    function($relation_model) use ($filters) {
        // Apply where condition with filters
        $relation_model->where($filters);
    }
// Paginate for the numbers of row requested
)->paginate($rows);
```

How to do that if `price` is not a property of table `items`?

Should I store price inside the table and update it on every new user relation added? (or every removed relation too).
Is this the correct approach?

I was thinking about website like `eBay` or other real-time auction that have a similar situation of mine: how do you think they have solved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a `user_items` table that keeps track of the items owned by user, I think something like this might work:

```
$result = Item::selectRaw('items.*, price_factor * (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_items WHERE user_items.item_id = items.id) AS price')
    ->with(['users'])
    ->havingRaw('price > ? AND price < ?', [5, 10])
    ->orderBy('price', 'asc')
    ->paginate($rows);
```

You can calculate the price on the fly and alias it. Finally you can apply a `havingRaw` clause to it that will check if the price is between the range it needs to be. Here's a working [example](https://implode.io/OeLWb5) of this in action.

There might be better ways to do this. I am also curious to know :)

Comment: Mmmh, with this raw query I can improve it as you showed. +1. I will give it a try. Thanks for reply!